# Codeigniter delete row from db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to delete row from db table by passing id. Please help me to pass id from the view correctly. Any help will be highly appreciated. Please let me know if any detailed information is needed so that I can provide it.

Here is my Model:

```
public function did_delete_row($user_id){ 

$query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('user_id' => $user_id));

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

    if ($this->db->delete('users',array('user_id','email','name','city'))) 

        {return true;}

        else

        {return false;}
    } else {return false;}

                }
```

Here is My view:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_row/'.$user_id);?">Delete</a>
```

Here is My controller:

```
  public function delete_row($user_id) {

        $this->load->model("model_admin");
        $this->model_admin->did_delete_row($user_id);

        }
```

Comment: You can append the query string to your URL. Like: `/delete_row?id=1`. Then you can retrieve the id using `$this->input->get('id');`

Comment: I have just edited my code. Could you check it now please?

Comment: The delete accepts second parameter as associative array (`WHERE` clause). You need `$this->db->delete('users',array('user_id' => $this->input->get('user_id')))`. Also you have semi colon `;` in your `get_where` clause

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Your **HTML**.... you should pass the `user_id_to_delete` like this:

```html
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_row/'.$user_id_to_delete);?>">Delete</a>
```

Now, in the `Controller` you should receive the `user_id_to_delete` variable into the `user_id` when it gets to the `delete_row()` method. Now, you can send it as a HTTP post transaction.

```js
public function delete_row($user_id) {   
    $this->load->model("model_admin");
    $this->model_admin->did_delete_row($user_id);
}
```

For the model you will get the `user_id` to delete. Here is the function for your admin model

```js
public function did_delete_row($id){
    $this -> db -> where('user_id', $id);
    $this -> db -> delete('users');
}
```

Finally, update the delete URL line as follows:

```html
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_row/'.$user['user_id']);?">Delete</a></td>
```

That Should work for you

Comment: I changed my code as per your advice but it generates errors for controller code. I guess something is wrong with my view. I don't know if I pass id correctly.

Comment: give your view and controller code for generating the view

Comment: I have just edited my question and added view and controller code for generating the view. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter 3:

Use - **$this->db->delete()**

```
$this->db->delete('mytable', array('id' => $id));  // Produces: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = $id
```

OR - Delete from multiple tables:

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$this->db->where('id', '5');
$this->db->delete($tables);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html